# Events with Socket.io in iOS

Tags: ios, socket.io, swift2

I am currently using the Socket.io client for swift, and I have been able to establish a connection to the server, but for some reason, I am unable to receive events. I have tried running it with debugging, and it receives the event from the iOS client, but it is not executing the addUser function. I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what it is.

**main.js**

```
var app = require('http').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(6979)

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  io.emit('hi there:');
});

io.on('addUser', function(username){
      console.log('ran addUser');
      io.emit(username);
      console.log(username);
 });
```

**Swift**

```
import UIKit
import Socket_IO_Client_Swift

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var name:String?
    let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6979", options: [.Log(true), .ForcePolling(true)])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func connect(sender: AnyObject) {
        socket.connect()
    }

    @IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    @IBAction func sendUsername(sender: AnyObject) {
        let username = "yay"
        socket.emit("addUser", username)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it (probably) should be

```
let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "/", options: [.Log(true), .ForcePolling(true)])
```

Then server side should be like

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('addUser', function(username){
        console.log('ran addUser');
        io.emit(username); // do you really need to do it?
        console.log(username);
    });

});
```

At least this should enable you to receive `addUser` event on server side.